# How to get Query String from a Service Reference in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, service-reference

Is there an easy way to see the entire `query string` from a `Service Reference` in Visual Studio? For example, I added the `Service Reference`: `http://server01:8101/Services/SalesOrders`

I'd like to see the actual request URL when a request is sent to the server, for example like so:
`http://server01:8101/Services/SalesOrders?SalesOrderNumber=123123&SalesOrderLine=2`

The reason for this is I'm building a custom handler to retrieve the XML data and can't use Visual Studio's add Service Reference due to incompatibility with SQL 2012 CLR. So I'd like to see the actual request URL and create a custom handler.

I have Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Couple of questions: We're talking about WCF services, right? What does the SQL 2012 CLR have to do with anything? This is  RESTful service (not SOAP)?

Comment: Correct, WCF services. I'm creating a class for SQL 2012 CLR and `System.ServiceModel` cannot be used and will not be fixed as documented here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/809697. This is a RESTful service.

Comment: You can generate the service class outside of Visual Studio and include that in your SQL CLR project. Use the `wsdl` command line tool to generate a .cs file for you, then add that to tyour CLR project.

Comment: I did a little search on what `wsdl` can do for me, but it looks like `VS2015` doesn't have it. I'm not sure what this is supposed to do? Is it supposed to get me the WSDL file then I can look into what the parameters of the query string is? Sorry, quite confused.

Comment: I generated the .cs file but it only contains comments. The warning was this: `Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
SOAP 1.1 binding was not found: WS-I's Basic Profile 1.1 consists of implementat
ion guidelines that recommend how a set of core Web services specifications shou
ld be used together to develop interoperable Web services. For the 1.1 Profile,
those specifications are SOAP 1.1, WSDL 1.1, UDDI 2.0, XML 1.0 and XML Schema.`